# How can I remove all Hyperlinks from a Word document with a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I remove all Hyperlinks from a Word document with a VBA macro?

In Excel I can select everything using VBA and use

```
Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

Is there something similar in Word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove all Hyperlinks from a word document using the following VBA macro.

```
Sub ClearHyperlinks()

Dim oField As Field

For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
If oField.Type = wdFieldHyperlink Then
oField.Unlink
End If
Next

Set oField = Nothing

End Sub
```